# Create a new column with a sum based on the value of three other columns

Tags: r

I have a data frame and I want to create another column based on the information of three different columns. I am using R.

I want to start counting on 0 and to add 2 in each new cell, based on a column Time and on Item and Participants information. I want to have 0 for the beginning of the Time counting (which is in ms) for each item of each participant.

```
df <- data.frame(Item=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2),  
             Part=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2), 
            Time=c(1234,1235,1236,345,346,347,1546,1547,1548,234,235,236))

   Item Part Time
1     1    1 1234
2     1    1 1235
3     1    1 1236
4     1    2  345
5     1    2  346
6     1    2  347
7     2    1 1546
8     2    1 1547
9     2    1 1548
10    2    2  234
11    2    2  235
12    2    2  236
```

With the new column the table would be something like:

```
   Item Part Time NewColumn
1     1    1 1234         0
2     1    1 1235         2
3     1    1 1236         4
4     1    2  345         0
5     1    2  346         2
6     1    2  347         4
7     2    1 1546         0
8     2    1 1547         2
9     2    1 1548         4
10    2    2  234         0
11    2    2  235         2
12    2    2  236         4
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you accept the answer so we can close this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case the structure stays as it is

```
library(dplyr)
result <- df %>% group_by(Part, Item) %>% mutate(NewColumn = seq (0,4,2))
```

I group by `Item` and `Part` and create a new column that counts 0, 2, 4

```
   Item Part Time NewColumn
1     1    1 1234         0
2     1    1 1235         2
3     1    1 1236         4
4     1    2  345         0
5     1    2  346         2
6     1    2  347         4
7     2    1 1546         0
8     2    1 1547         2
9     2    1 1548         4
10    2    2  234         0
11    2    2  235         2
12    2    2  236         4
```

In order to be more flexible (if you have more than 3 rows per group), you can use

```
result <- df %>% group_by(Part, Item) %>% mutate(NewColumn = 2* (row_number()-1))
```

which will will generate numbers in the sequence 0, 2, 4, 6, 8,...

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes, I have more than 3 rows (a lot more), and so the second answer would be the best solution, but I get an error: **Error: could not find function "%>%"**. I also tried this solution: **dat[, csum := c(0,cumsum(Time-Time+2)), by=c("Part","Item")]**, since I want the count based on Time, but I get another error: **Warning messages:
1: In `[.data.table`(df, , `:=`(NewCol, seq(0, nrow(df), 2)), by = list(Item,  :
  RHS 1 is length 7 (greater than the size (3) of group 1). The last 4 element(s) will be discarded.**

Comment: it is a chaining operator for `dplyr`, so for the second solution, you would also have to load the library using `library(dplyr)`. If you didn't install it earlier, use `install.packages("dplyr")`

Comment: I am sorry. I was sure that I had activated **dplyr**. I tried again and it worked. Thanks and sorry for my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.table(df)
df[, NewCol := seq(0,nrow(df),2), by=list(Item,Part)]
```

Comment: Thanks! This works but I get a warning message: **Warning messages:
1: In `[.data.table`(df, , `:=`(NewCol, seq(0, nrow(df), 2)), by = list(Item,  :
  RHS 1 is length 7 (greater than the size (3) of group 1). The last 4 element(s) will be discarded.**. The same I get with: **dat[, csum := c(0,cumsum(Time-Time+2)), by=c("Part","Item")]**. Anyway, I wanted the count to be based on Time and your solution does not warranty that if Time is not sorted, right?

Answer (score 1):

Er... `df = cbind(df,NewColumn=c(0,2,4))`?

Comment: This assumes that every Item,Part goes by 3.

Comment: True, and the OP has chosen an example that abides by that, maybe not by mere chance...?

Comment: You piece of code does not work if the data are not sorted as in the OP example. Do not assume it is the case.

Answer (score 1):

+1 for library(plyr)

```
    library(plyr)
    ddply(df, c("Item","Part"), mutate,NewColumn = seq(0,4,2))



    Item Part   Time NewColumn
     1    1     1234    0
     1    1     1235    2
     1    1     1236    4
     1    2     345     0
     1    2     346     2
     1    2     347     4
     2    1     1546    0
     2    1     1547    2
     2    1     1548    4
     2    2     234     0
     2    2     235     2
     2    2     236     4
```